# How to capture and display data from a list, without having to create functions for each one?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following problem: I want that every time that one of the elements of the list is clicked, the data-link value is printed, if I need to create a function for each of the elements of the list.

```
<ul id="programs">
    <li id="design" data-link="www.monster.inc">Diseño</li>
    <li id="fashion" data-link="www.iceage.inc">Moda</li>
    <li id="management" data-link="www.transilvania.inc">Management</li>
    <li id="arts" data-link="www.ralph.inc">Artes</li>
</ul>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

    var one = document.getElementById("design");

    one.onclick = function() {
        var x = one.getAttribute("data-link"); 
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }

    var two = document.getElementById("fashion");

    two.onclick = function() {
        var y = two.getAttribute("data-link"); 
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
    }

    var three = document.getElementById("management");

    three.onclick = function() {
        var z = three.getAttribute("data-link"); 
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
    }

    var four = document.getElementById("arts");

    four.onclick = function() {
        var w = four.getAttribute("data-link"); 
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = w;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Using jQuery, that's a single command: `$('programs li').click(function () { $('#demo').text($(this).data('link')); });`

Comment: You can create a `<span>` inside the `<p>` and make it hidden by default.
then onclick the span is visible, just by using css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two selectors for the above structure.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('[data-link]');
```

and

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('#programs > li');
```

And then loop over the NodeList and attach the function to `onclick` prop. I recommend `addEventListener`, however.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('[data-link]'),
    demo  = document.getElementById("demo");

links.forEach(function(link){

    link.onclick = function() {
        var x = this.getAttribute("data-link"); 
        demo.innerHTML = x;
    }

});
```

```html
<ul id="programs">
    <li id="design" data-link="www.monster.inc">Diseño</li>
    <li id="fashion" data-link="www.iceage.inc">Moda</li>
    <li id="management" data-link="www.transilvania.inc">Management</li>
    <li id="arts" data-link="www.ralph.inc">Artes</li>
</ul>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of solutions for this one, with or without jQuery.

Here's a simple one that only updates your one list and not other broadly selected elements on the page.

```
var list = document.getElementById("programs").getElementsByTagName("li")
for (var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
{

  list[i].onclick = function() {
        var x = this.getAttribute("data-link"); 
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the onclick event to the parent `ul` element and use the `event.target` property to access the child element on which the click happened.

```js
var programs = document.getElementById("programs");

programs.onclick = function(e) {
  var link = e.target.getAttribute("data-link");
  if (link)
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = link;
};
```

```html
<ul id="programs">
  <li id="design" data-link="www.monster.inc">Diseño</li>
  <li id="fashion" data-link="www.iceage.inc">Moda</li>
  <li id="management" data-link="www.transilvania.inc">Management</li>
  <li id="arts" data-link="www.ralph.inc">Artes</li>
</ul>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

You need not iterate through each `li` and attach `onclick` events to them individually.